# Rails module names with acronym inflections

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looks like inflections don't work for module names with the nesting level more than one.

If you have the following in your `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'VCloud'
end
```

Then when you create a directory under `app/`, say `app/services/vcloud/` you will get two modules:

```
Vcloud #=> Vcloud
VCloud #=> VCloud
```

But if you create a directory with a higher nesting level, say `app/services/vmware/vcloud/` you will get only one module:

```
Vmware::Vcloud #=> Vmware::Vcloud
Vmware::VCloud #=> NameError: uninitialized constant Vmware::VCloud
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: i did not know that inflection has anything to do with classes. i though it would handle string strictly?

Comment: @phoet - Rails uses `Inflector` internally to resolve missing constants.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with this is a bug. You can go around it with (within initializers):

```
module ActiveSupport::Inflector
  def underscore_with_acronym_fix(string)
    words = string.split('::')
    return words.map(&method(:underscore)).join('/') unless words.one?
    underscore_without_acronym_fix(string)
  end

  alias_method_chain :underscore, :acronym_fix
end
```

I'll make a pull request to fix this, however will need slightly more time to confirm it will not break anything. There are quite a lot of cases here.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if i could replicate this "issue".

Tried this running rails console.

`> ActiveSupport::Inflector.camelize 'vcloud'
=> "Vcloud"`

`> ActiveSupport::Inflector.camelize 'v_cloud'
=> "VCloud"`

There are test cases for all sorts of combinations below.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/test/inflector_test_cases.rb